# startx frozen screen with weird VGA

Tags: x11, xorg, startx

I am trying to configure a computer on Zaphode mode. The machine is running Linux Mint 19.2. The graphic card is not working properly. I first need make it work so I can work on Zaphode mode.

The computer uses a grpahic card named TN 750. Its just a PCI wrapper for a SoC named SM750 from Silicon Motion.

After many, many days I succeeded in displaying text mode on the graphic card. By default when I boot Linux Mint, it briefly shows the Linux Mint logo and then the image freezes black with a frozen cursor.

I can switch to tty1, for instance, using ctrl + alt + f1. There, I run

```
sudo startx xterm -- :1 vt2
```

but then again I got a frozen image. I can still switch among the others tty. I know that the SM750 has a framebuffer driver named sm750fb that is loaded by default. Checking Xorg.0.log it seems that it tries to load VESA and fbdev drivers for the graphic card.

If I run htop, I can see the following process:

Here are the logs for xorg:

Xorg.0.log: https://pastebin.com/HgE4iMu8

ps -aux:

```
ps -aux | grep Xorg
root       844  0.5  1.1 453240 38508 tty7     Ssl+ 00:29   0:01 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
```

lspci:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Silicon Motion, Inc. SM750 (rev a1)
```

I also installed a xf86 driver from siliconmotion. It also seems that X tries to use it but as I don't understand very well the logs, I am unsure of what is going on.

```
apt-cache search siliconmotion
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion - X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-hwe-16.04 - Transitional package for xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion-hwe-16.04
```

My last hope is that I can use at least this graphic card at VESA mode on zaphode mode. But first I need to find out why there is no graphical output

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the `xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion` is from the Xorg project and for [much older Silicon Motion chips only.](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man4/siliconmotion.4.xhtml)

> The siliconmotion driver supports PCI and AGP video cards based on the following Silicon Motion chips:
>
> - Lynx        SM910
> - LynxE       SM810
> - Lynx3D      SM820
> - LynxEM      SM710
> - LynxEM+     SM712
> - Lynx3DM     SM720
> - Cougar3DR   SM731
> - MSOC        SM501,SM502

The current [download page of SiliconMotion](http://www.siliconmotion.com/downloads/index.html) offers downloads only for the SM76x (which may or may not be related to SM750) for Windows, macOS and Android only.

From your log, the X server seems to be initially using the `modesetting` driver, but fails to detect any connected outputs:

```
[    19.876] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 disconnected
[    19.876] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[    19.876] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[    19.876] (WW) modeset(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
[    19.876] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 disconnected
[    19.876] (II) modeset(0): Output HDMI-1 disconnected
[    19.876] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[    19.876] (WW) modeset(0): Unable to find connected outputs - setting 1024x768 initial framebuffer
```

On the other hand, these might be the outputs of the iGPU within your CPU.

The [sm750fb](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/staging/sm750fb) driver seems to be in a "staging" directory, so it might be a bit rough around the edges yet. [Its README file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/staging/sm750fb/readme) suggests there might be some things you'll need to take into account:

> Important:
>       if you have vesafb enabled in your config then /dev/fb0 will be created by vesafb
>       and this driver will use fb1, fb2. In that case, you need to configure your X-server to  use fb1. Another simple althernative is to disable vesafb from your config.

According to that, adding `Option "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"` to your X server configuration might be helpful. See [the man page of the fbdev driver](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man4/fbdev.4.xhtml) for more info.